# Enforce case sensitive import path

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, eslint, nuxtjs

our dev team is using all operating systems. On OSX and Win auto-imports for Vue components and with lower case, but the physical file of component is starting with upper case.

When we build our application on a server machine (Linux) then build fail because of wrong paths.

For instance, consider existing vue file MyComponent.vue:

this is path which is added on win / osx: `import MyComponent from '~/components/myComponent'`
and this is path which is added on Linux and also is required for a successful build: `import MyComponent from '~/components/MyComponent'`

Can you tell me if there is a way how to enforce correct import path, for instance with es lint? Thank you. We are using Nuxt in our Vue app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this webpack plugin?
https://github.com/Urthen/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin

Comment: yes, I added it to nuxt config and then build failed for some internal error

Comment: Could you post the error messages for further investigation?

Answer (score 0):

The `import/no-unresolved` rule takes care of case sensitive paths. Here is the documentation for the rule [ESLint No Unresolved](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unresolved.md#casesensitive)